# Prevent changing schema in Spring Boot with two DBs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two DBs in my Spring Boot app, one configured with appliation.properties:

```
spring.secondDatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.10.10:3306/db1
spring.secondDatasource.username=user
spring.secondDatasource.password=pass

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

and another via DataSource:

```
@Configuration
public class SecondDbConnectionConfig {



    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://20.20.20:3306/db2");
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUsername("user");
        dataSource.setPassword("pass");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

When I run the app, both schemas are updated with my domain model.
I want to update a domain model only for app.prop configured DB.
As to DataSource configured DB, I don't want to make any changes, just read.
How to fix this config?

Comment: Do you using Entity Manager and Transaction Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `DriverManagerDataSource` for production. It's just suitable for your testing environment. (It does not have connection pool, just create new connection on the fly)

Your datasource uses your JpaProperties config from your `spring.jpa.*` properties. So you need to override it:

```
@Bean(name = "your-entity-manager-factory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
        @Qualifier("testdatasource") DataSource dataSource, // Here you must annotate your DriverManagerDataSource  bean with @Bean("testdatasource")
        JpaProperties jpaProperties) {
    // Here you clone and modify JpaProperties
    Map<String, String> hibernateConfig = jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource);
    hibernateConfig.remove("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto");
    return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .persistenceUnit("testPu")
            .properties(hibernateConfig)
            .build();
}
```

You may config additional transaction manager.